# java class path issue with properties file

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I have a batch file to set class path before calling the java main method, see code below

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz2.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz3.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz5.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz6.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;/resource

java -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.xyz.main
```

if I keep my properties file inside the resource folder it works fine, but if I leave it in root folder it doesn't work.

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz2.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz3.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz5.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz6.jar

java -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.xyz.main
```

the above class path setting don't work am getting null pointer exception

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz1.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz2.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz3.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz4.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz5.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libs/xyz6.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;/

java -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.xyz.main
```

the above class path setting don't work am getting the same null pointer exception.

Am using java util properties as below.

```
  InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.properties");
  getProperties().load(inputStream);
```

it will be really nice if someone can help me find, why this happens. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include complete class path

**java -classpath .;%CLASSPATH% com.xyz.main**

you can also set multiple specification Refer the below link, 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 4):

Call `getResourceAsStream()` causes java to look for a resource available for current class loader, i.e. one that can be found in your class path. If you want to read file from file system use `new`new FileInputStream("abc.properties")` instead. If you want to continue reading file from resource you must include it into your classpath either into one of your jar files or as a separate entry.

You can even implement logic that reads file from class path and then overrides the values with file found in file system.

BTW take a look on [jackarata configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) package that has this feature built-in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include "./" in your CLASSPATH.  You are effectively telling the JVM to exclude it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the classpath are checked from the current directory `.` would do the best
Even if you do not include your properties file in the resource folder and run the java program as mention below it will work perfectly

```
java -cp .;%CLASSPATH% com.xyz.main
```

**NOTE**: cp is the shorthand for classpath